# Употребление слов "уверить" и "заверить"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Последнее время замечаю в СМИ употребление сочетания Х "заверил" У. Помнится, нас учили, что "заверить" можно документ, а кого-то- "уверить". Норма изменилась?Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Из Ожегова:
ЗАВЕРИТЬ,  1. кого  (что) в чем.  Уверить, убеждая  в чем-н., обещая  что-н. 3. в  своей  преданности,  дружбе. 2. что. Удостоверить, скрепив подписью,  печатью.  3. подпись.  3.  копию.

УВЕРИТЬ,  кого  (что) в чем.  То  же,  что убедить  (в  1 знач.).  У.  в своей правоте. Смею вас у.  (заверяю вас).  || несов. уверять.  Уверяю тебя, что я  прав.

Возможно, что "уверить" (заставить "поверить")- это основной вариант, а "заверить" дополнительно  отражает особую заинтересованность действующего лица в конечном результате.

Answer (score 1):

Из контекста **Х заверил Y в том** в текущее время следует, что **Х** искренне или по правилам этикета выразил уверенность в свершении чего-то, а м. б. даже дал **Y** обещание вплоть до гарантии при зависимости грядущего события или ситуации от него. При этом вера и надежда самого **Y** могут оставаться в произвольном значении.

Comment: Заверил  -  значит  пообещал,  под  своё  честное  слово.  А  уверил  -  это  когда   и  Игрек   в   это   поверил.  Так ?

Comment: Да, Вы, **bernard**, правильно поняли мои слова. Было ли там дано "честное слово" или нет, это факт второстепенный. *Заверил*, по моему пониманию, которое изложено в ответе на вопрос, это констатация третьим лицом, наблюдателем, самого факта декларации согласия или обещания. А насчёт *уверил* пусть сам **Y** об этом заверит читателей и слушателей. Которые вправе и далее иметь своё мнение об искренности фигурантов диалога. :) А уж как будут развиваться события и обнажение истины, покажет реальное физическое время, а не одноимённая телепрограмма.

Comment: Еще о том же. УВЕРИТЬ кого-то  –   убедить кого-то с гарантированным результатом. Это не так просто, поэтому чаще встречается  вариант «уверять», обозначающий  процесс,  не доведенный до конца.
ЗАВЕРИТЬ кого-то – это  высказать свою точку зрения, приведя убедительные доказательства ее правильности и «поставив печать» личной уверенности. Поэтому слово  в своем  втором значении используется в канцелярской тематике. Примеры: Есть уверенность в том, что все будет сделано качественно и в срок", — заверил российский лидер. Не может быть! Ведь он заверил нас.  Представляешь, он уверял нас.